# how to implement vertx webclient mtls?

Tags: vert.x

server:

```
    HttpServerOptions options = new HttpServerOptions()
              .setSsl(true)
              .setClientAuth(ClientAuth.REQUIRED)
              .setPemKeyCertOptions(new PemKeyCertOptions().addCertPath(path+"/cert.pem").setKeyPath(path+"/key.pem"))
              ;
            HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer(options);
```

client:

```
        WebClientOptions options = new WebClientOptions()
                  .setSsl(true)               
                  .setPemKeyCertOptions(new PemKeyCertOptions().addCertPath(path+"/cert.pem").setKeyPath(path+"/key.pem"))                    
                  .setTrustAll(true);
                WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx, options);
```

when invoking the client the server shows the error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Empty client certificate chain

which, i assume, indicates that the client is not sending the certificate to the server.
Question: how do you implement mtls with vertx WebClient ?

Answer (score 0):

adding:

```
.setTrustOptions(new PemTrustOptions().addCertPath(path+"/cert.pem"))
```

to client and server options seems to solve the issue.

any comments, explanations why are welcome.